# Button disable from false to true

Tags: angularjs

Im loading in a number in chosen.number. it can be all from 1 to 10.

```
<button name="stop" ng-click="stop()" ng-disabled="true">Stoppa</button>
```

Now i want it to check if chosen.number is 1 OR 2, it should make the stop button disable to false. Any clues? thank you in advance.

```
 $scope.stop = function (time) {

 if (chosen.number == 1 || chosen.number == 2)
  $scope.stop.disable = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can bind variable `IsOneOrTwo` to disable property

#### html

```
<button name="stop" ng-click="stop()" ng-disabled="IsOneOrTwo">Stoppa</button>
```

#### controller

```
...
$scope.IsOneOrTwo=false;
$scope.stop = function (time) {
     if (chosen.number == 1 ||chosen.number == 2)
      $scope.IsOneOrTwo = true;
     }
```